# lldb gives "attach failed" when trying to "run" an arm64 binary on macOS 11.1

Tags: macos, lldb, apple-m1

This is on an M1 mini, running 11.1 with an updated Xcode.  (All pending updates have been applied.)  SIP has not been disabled (if it can even be, on the M1).

We have a program we're using to test an `mmap()` failure in our application being ported.  We build the test program like this:

```
cc -v -arch arm64 -m64 -Wl,-no_adhoc_codesign -o mapfail mapfail.c
```

Then, we sign it.  It appears to be correctly signed:

```
@macarm[git:master]$ codesign -vvv mapfail
mapfail: valid on disk
mapfail: satisfies its Designated Requirement
@macarm[git:master]$
```

We have enabled developer mode on the system.  We also added my user to the `_developer` group.  My user is not an administrator, but I tried it as one and got the same thing.

When we run the program it gets a segmentation fault (SIGSEGV), so we want to debug it with `lldb`, but this happens:

```
@macarm[git:master]$ lldb mapfail
(lldb) target create "mapfail"
Current executable set to '/Users/layer/mapfail' (arm64).
(lldb) run
error: process exited with status -1 (attach failed ((os/kern) invalid argument))
(lldb)
```

Searches for this have yielded no information, even on the Apple developer forums.

Code for `mapfail.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <mach/mach.h>
#include <mach/machine/vm_param.h>

#define nat long

#define UseMAP_ANON
/* define UseDevZero */

#define FIROUNDUP(a, n) (((a) + ((n) - 1)) & ~((n) - 1))
#define FIROUNDDOWN(a, n) ((a) & ~((n) - 1))

int bucket_o_zeros = -1;
int ChunkSize;

# ifdef UseMAP_ANON
#   define FIMAP_ANON MAP_ANON
# else
#   define FIMAP_ANON 0
# endif

typedef struct {
    char *base;     /* lowest address -- 64k aligned */
    char *pos;      /* 1+ highest address allocated */
    char *commit;   /* 1+ highest address committed */
} heap_descriptor;

heap_descriptor test1, test2;
unsigned nat test1_base, test1_size;

int
ok_to_map(unsigned nat base, unsigned nat top)
{
    /* check if the specified memory is free */
    unsigned nat address = base;
    vm_size_t size;
    mach_port_t object_name;
    task_t task = mach_task_self();
    struct vm_region_basic_info_64 info;
    mach_msg_type_number_t info_count = VM_REGION_BASIC_INFO_COUNT_64;
    kern_return_t retval;
    int res = 0;

    retval = vm_region_64(task, &address, &size, VM_REGION_BASIC_INFO_64,
              (vm_region_info_64_t)&info, &info_count, &object_name);
    if (retval == KERN_NO_SPACE) {
    res = 1;
    } else if ((retval == KERN_SUCCESS) && (address > top)) {
    res = 1;
    }
    if (object_name != MACH_PORT_NULL)
    mach_port_deallocate(mach_task_self(), object_name);

    printf("maping from 0x%lx to 0x%lx is %s\n", base, top, res ? "OK" : "BAD");
    return res;
}

char *
setup_heap( heap_descriptor *hd, unsigned nat base, unsigned nat size)
{
    /* allocate memory at the given address, and return the address
     * which was allocated
     */
       
    char *res = (char *)MAP_FAILED;

    /* initial setup of heap when there is nothing to map in or commit */
    base = FIROUNDDOWN(base, ChunkSize);
    size = FIROUNDUP(size, ChunkSize);

    /* we demand that OS puts memory at our base, so we can grow later */
    if (base == 0 || ok_to_map(base, base+size)) {
    res = (char *) mmap((void *) base, size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE | PROT_EXEC,
                MAP_PRIVATE | FIMAP_ANON | (base ? MAP_FIXED : 0),
                bucket_o_zeros, 0);
    }
    if (res != (char *) MAP_FAILED) {
    /* success - check alignment */
    if (base == 0) {
        nat diff;
        base = (unsigned nat) res;
        res = (char *) FIROUNDUP((nat) res, ChunkSize);
        diff = ((unsigned nat)res - base);
        if (diff > 0) {
        /* this had been over-requested already */
        size -= ChunkSize;
        /* must munmap the two ends */
        munmap((caddr_t) base, diff);
        munmap((caddr_t) (res + size), diff);
        }
    }
    /* initialize the heap descriptor */
    hd->pos = hd->base = res;
    hd->commit = (char *) (hd->base + size);
    return hd->base;
    } else {
    return 0;   /* failure */
    }
}

int
try_setup_heap(char *kind, heap_descriptor *hd, unsigned nat base, unsigned nat size)
{
    /* try to allocate where first requested, and then let the system decide.
     * return true or false depending on whether it worked.
     */
     
    char *result_base;

    base = FIROUNDUP(base,ChunkSize);
    size = FIROUNDUP(size,ChunkSize);

    /* ask for a specific area */
    if (setup_heap(hd, base, size)) return 1;   /* success */

    /* now ask for any location */
    if ((result_base = setup_heap(hd, 0, size + ChunkSize)) == 0) {
    fprintf(stderr,
        "Unable to reserve at %ld (0x%lx) bytes of memory for the %s heap\n",
        size, size, kind);
    return 0;
    } else {
    fprintf(stderr,
        "Unable to reserve 0x%lx for the %s heap,\n using 0x%lx instead\n",
        base, kind, (unsigned nat) result_base);
    return 1;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv, char**envp)
{
    ChunkSize = getpagesize();
#if defined(UseDevZero)
    if(bucket_o_zeros == -1){
    bucket_o_zeros = open("/dev/zero", O_RDWR);
    }
#endif
    if (argc > 2) {
    sscanf(argv[1], "%lx", &test1_base);
    sscanf(argv[2], "%lx", &test1_size);
    if (try_setup_heap("test1", &test1, test1_base, test1_size)) {
        printf("test1 heap mapped from 0x%lx to 0x%lx\n",
           (unsigned nat) test1.base, (unsigned nat)test1.commit);
    } else {
        printf("test1 not mapped\n");
    }
    } else {
    unsigned nat addr = 0x100000000;
    unsigned nat size = 0x100000;
    int i, n, didit=0;;
    sscanf(argv[1], "%d", &n);
    for (i=0; i < n; i++) {
        if (try_setup_heap("test2", &test2, addr, size)) {
        printf("test1 heap mapped from 0x%lx to 0x%lx\n",
               (unsigned nat) test2.base, (unsigned nat)test2.commit);
        didit++;
        }
        addr += 0x100000000;
    }
    printf("Total mappings: %d\n", didit);
    }
}

/*
 * To compile on M1 with debugging:
 * cc -v -arch arm64 -m64 -Wl,-no_adhoc_codesign -o mapfail mapfail.c
 */
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the binary run outside of the debugger?  I tried a `int main(){return 0;}` do-nothing program, compiled it with your command line, signed it ad-hoc `codesign -s - a.out` and I can run it and debug it. This should help you to isolate where the problem is -- does a do-nothing program ad-hoc codesigned work?  Does a do-nothing program signed with your signature work?  Does your app ad-hoc codesigned work?  Are you using entitlements?

Comment: I redid the test without `-Wl,-no_adhoc_codesign` and I cannot debug it.  Are you on an M1 or Intel Big Sur?

Comment: How did you compile it?  With Xcode or `cc` on the command line?

Comment: On a M1 Mac mini running macOS 11.1.  `echo 'int main(){return 0;}'>a.c`; `clang a.c`; `./a.out` works, `% lldb -b -o r a.out` works. Compiling `clang -Wl,-no_adhoc_codesign a.c` will not be runnable (`./a.out` will be killed), it must be at least ad-hoc codesigned to run  (`codesign -s - a.out` or sign with your own code signing profile.)  Your original description doesn't say whether the program *runs* - does it even run?  Is this a "lldb can't debug any cmdline process" bug, is it an "lldb can't debug THIS process" bug?

Comment: OK, that works for me.  I think something must be happening with my test program because I'm using `mmap()`.

Comment: The original program gets a SEGV.  I said that in the description.

Comment: I've added the test program to the question above.

Comment: The presence of a call to mmap() doesn't impact the debugger at the point of launching the process or attaching to the process--the error you're showing makes it look like lldb never attaches.  Can you put a breakpoint on main and run to that?  Is it really working fine until you get to the mmap() call and then the debugger or process exits?

Answer (score 0):

This issue is known and as C/C++ extension binaries are yet to be built for Apple Silicon, it does not work as of now.

Refer to below link to keep a track:

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/6595