# VS Code debug Rust program: process exited with status -1 (Error 1) on Mac M1

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, rust, lldb, exit-code

Update: from reading others with same error, I'm wondering if this somehow specific to Mac M1. But it's strange the same operations work from the Mac Terminal, just not in VS Code.

Running either `lldb target/debug/rust` or `rust-lldb target/debug/rust` from the VS Code Terminal will open the debugger, but running the program (with or without breakpoint at the main function) returns:

```
error: process exited with status -1 (attach failed ((os/kern) invalid argument))
```

I'm running on Mac M1. Running the same stuff from Mac Terminal works fine.

From VS Code Terminal:

```
rust % which lldb
/usr/bin/lldb
rust % which rust-lldb
/Users/me/.cargo/bin/rust-lldb
```

which is the same as Mac Terminal.

Comment: Commenting myself. Seems to have to do with Apple app signing issues? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65331087/lldb-gives-attach-failed-when-trying-to-run-an-arm64-binary-on-macos-11-1. Not sure why Mac Terminal behavior would differ from VS Code terminal.

Comment: Something to do with Mac M1?

Comment: Probably related to https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/7035